# Redirect stdin and stdout in child in c

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I need to create a client-server app (using sockets), the basic idea is:

- client sends string
- server receives string and sends it as stdin of another app
- server reads stdout of the app
- server sends answer to client.

The "other app" is a closed source calc (a calculator which reads from stdin the sort of `4 5 +` and prints `9`).

I'm trying to create a double pipe on the server, fork, and use this pipes to redirect stdin and stdout of the calc:

```
if(!fork())
{

    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(STDIN_FILENO);

    dup2(outfd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    dup2(infd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

    close(outfd[0]); /* Not required for the child */
    close(outfd[1]);
    close(infd[0]);
    close(infd[1]);

    system("./calc/calc ");
    exit(0);
}
```

and from the server write on one pipe and read the other

```
    close(outfd[0]); /* These are being used by the child */
    close(infd[1]);

    char c;
    do
    {
        c=getchar();
        write(outfd[1],&c,1);
    }while(c!='\n');
    input[read(infd[0],input,100)] = 0; /* Read from child’s stdout */

    printf("%s",input);

    close(outfd[1]);
    close(infd[0]);
```

I know this is very incomplete, but I think it should at least print the output of the first line in calc.

(Full code)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

int outfd[2];
int infd[2];

pipe(outfd); /* Where the parent is going to write to */
pipe(infd); /* From where parent is going to read */

if(!fork())
{

    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(STDIN_FILENO);

    dup2(outfd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    dup2(infd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

    close(outfd[0]); /* Not required for the child */
    close(outfd[1]);
    close(infd[0]);
    close(infd[1]);

    //system("/usr/bin/bc -q");
    system("./calc/calc ");
    exit(0);
}
else
{

    char input[100];

    close(outfd[0]); /* These are being used by the child */
    close(infd[1]);

    //write(outfd[1],"2^32\n",5); /* Write to child’s stdin */
    //write(outfd[1],"2 4 +\n",6);
    char c;
    do
    {
        c=getchar();
        write(outfd[1],&c,1);
    }while(c!='\n');
    input[read(infd[0],input,100)] = 0; /* Read from child’s stdout */

    printf("%s",input);

    close(outfd[1]);
    close(infd[0]);

}
return 0;
```

It's very basic, but it's just for testing. When I execute it, it does nothing.

If I `ps -e | grep calc` during the execution, I can see it is running, but whatever I type doesn't seems to do anything.

Comment: The child is probably buffering its output. It will flush the output when it exits, but it's probably waiting for `EOF` on `stdin` before it does that.

Comment: Is it your `calc` binary? I can compile and run your code against a common `calc` installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving:

```
close(outfd[1]);
```

between the `do-while` loop and `input[read(infd[0],input,100)] = 0;`.

This will send `EOF` on `calc`'s stdin. It will exit, and this will flush its output buffer, so there will be something to read.

Your code is deadlocked: you're waiting for output before you close the pipe, but it's waiting for you to close the pipe before it sends output.

Comment: You sir, are a genius!
I'm now going to try this on the actual code I planned to use, but with this example it works wonders!. Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm sorry to trouble you again, but what could I do show the response without closing the pipe? (or at least a way to reopen it afterwards).
thanks so much

Comment: You can't reopen a pipe. If you're trying to perform multiple interactions with an application, you need to get it to flush its buffers after every request. Whether this is possible, and how to do it, depends on the details of the application. If you can modify the program you're talking to, you can disable its buffering with `setbuf()`. If it's out of your control, you might have to use a pty. Perhaps you should consider writing your controlling program as an Expect script instead of in C.

Comment: Thank you so much! that setbuf() did the trick!
I'm still going to search for an alternative that doesn't involve changing calc code, but this works great for now!