# How to fork a child process and redirect all of the program's output to the child process?

Tags: c, fork, glibc

I am writing one task which interposition one other program's `printf()`.It forks one child process and and redirect all of the program's output to the child process. The code below is what I have written which haven't run yet and I need to add this function on it, I guess.

```
int printf(char* format, ... )
{
    int res;
    static void *(*mallocp)(size_t size);
    char *error;
    if (!mallocp) {
    mallocp = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "printf");
        if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL) {
            fputs(error, stderr);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    res=mallocp(format, args);
    va_end(args);
    return res;
}
```

I find one similar solution but a little different. [Redirect stdin and stdout in child in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736042/redirect-stdin-and-stdout-in-child-in-c)
I don't really know after I fork one child process and configure pipe well, how can I let parents process go on with the system "printf"`mallocp` to give the stdout which should be redirected to child process. (may be some thing like `system("./calc/calc ");`in that example) I am new in this field. Could you tell me ?

BTW, I don't know if I miss understand the implement of the whole process because It is one question and I don't know the official solution.

Comment: What is the _actual problem_ you are trying to solve this way?

Answer (score 0):

Use "dup2" and replace the "stdout" with "pipe" write file descriptor.

I assume your pipe is configured well from parent to child.

Then child can read from other end.

dup2(fd, 1); //1 is for stdout

**Second option:(in case your pipe is not good any more)**

Use shared memory.

Create shared memory object.

Redirect STDOUT from parent to shared memory.

Child can see it.

here is an example
http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/shm/example-1.html

Comment: Well, the link is not my code ,just a similar example. I think `system("./calc/calc ");` is some place I need to change according to my qestion. Becaue I need parent process to implement the system `printf` while child listenning to stdout

Comment: Try shared memory object. Updated answer